# Twig current time between two times

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have given two times(doctrine type time) and want to check, if the current time is between these times in a for-if-loop. I use the [Date compare](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/date.html) from twig. My code looks like this:

```
 {% for time in restaurant.openingHours if ((time.day == day) and (date(time.opening) <= date()) and (date(time.closing) >= date())) %}
    <span class="restaurant_info green"></span>
 {% else %}
    <span class="restaurant_info red"></span>
 {% endfor %}
```

The last condition(`date(time.closing) >= date()`) is false but shut be true. Has anybody a idea to fix this problem?

Comment: Have you got errors ??

Comment: Please post the contents of time.opening and time.closing and your current date().

Answer (score 2):

For oversight sake I would change your code and split the forloop and if statement. In order to check what is going wrong just dump the variables in the twig, like followed.

```
{%dump(time.opening)%}
{%dump(time.closing)%}
{%dump(date)%}

  {% for time in restaurant.openingHours  %}
        {%if ((time.day == day) and (date(time.opening) <= date()) and (date(time.closing) >= date()))%}
        <span class="restaurant_info green"></span>
         {% else %}
        <span class="restaurant_info red"></span>
        {%endif%}
     {% endfor %}
```